# Collapsing lists in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list

```
lst <- list(c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1"), 
            c("", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R2", "R2"),
            c("", "", "", "U1", "U2", "U3"))
```

Where the output is

```
[[1]]
[1] "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1"

[[2]]
[1] ""   "R1" "R2" "R2" "R2" "R2"

[[3]]
[1] ""   ""   ""   "U1" "U2" "U3"
```

---

Now, I want to have a single vector with the elements combined like so

```
out <- paste0(lst[[1]], lst[[2]], lst[[3]])
```

Where the output would be

```
[1] "A1"     "A1R1"   "A1R2"   "A1R2U1" "A1R2U2" "A1R2U3"
```

How can I do this more dynamically (e.g. for longer/shorter lists)? I was trying to use `sapply`, etc. but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with just

```
do.call("paste0", lst)
# [1] "A1"     "A1R1"   "A1R2"   "A1R2U1" "A1R2U2" "A1R2U3"
```

This passes all the columns of `lst` as parameters to `paste0` so it's basically like doing

```
paste0(list[[1]], list[[2]], list[[3]])
```

but it will work no matter how many vectors you have in `lst`

In base R, `do.call()` is as close as we get to a "splat" type operator that Pythonhas. The `rlang` package has introduced another alternative with the bang-bang-bang operator. But you do have to build the expression and evaluate it explicitly.

```
library(rlang)
eval_tidy(expr(paste0(!!!lst)))
# [1] "A1"     "A1R1"   "A1R2"   "A1R2U1" "A1R2U2" "A1R2U3"
```

Comment: Phantastic, need to look into `do.call`. Coming from `Python`, admittedly. Will accept the answer as soon as it's possible, thanks.

Comment: @Jan Some additional context, possibly helpful: `do.call("rbind",list_of_data_frames)` is probably the single most common `do.call` idiom. Both **dplyr** and **data.table** have specialized (fast) functions for that specific purpose. If you want to venture beyond base R, some folks would use `purrr::pmap` for this or related tasks where you're mapping a function over multiple inputs.

Comment: @joran: Thanks @joran. First I'd like to understand base `R`, eventually climbing up the ladder in the future. The syntax of `R` is weird sometimes (at least to me). If you like, feel free to post an answer using `purrr` and I'd happily upvote it.

Comment: @Jan Also take look at `do.call`'s good friend `Reduce(paste0, lst)`. I believe a function with near idenditacl name/behavior exists in Python, though it's been a while.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [MrFlick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49617112/3330437), the tidyverse-flavored answer uses `purrr::pmap`.

```
pmap_chr(lst, paste0)
# [1] "A1"     "A1R1"   "A1R2"   "A1R2U1" "A1R2U2" "A1R2U3"
```

This uses a variant of `pmap` (parallel map) that explicitly returns a character vector. The vanilla version, `pmap(lst, paste0)`, returns a list of the same length as `lst`, with each element as the output of a call to `paste0`.

```
[[1]]
[1] "A1"

[[2]]
[1] "A1R1"

[[3]]
[1] "A1R2"

[[4]]
[1] "A1R2U1"

[[5]]
[1] "A1R2U2"

[[6]]
[1] "A1R2U3"
```