# Using a nested loop to automate the creation of formulas for statistical analysis

Tags: r, for-loop

Let's say that I have a longitudinal study that measures the various facets of Quality of Life (QOL) across 5 different time points. Let's say that there are 4 facets of QOL: (1) social, (2) psychological, (3) physical, and (4) emotional. Each facet is measured a total of 5 times throughout the entire study. Each time point * facet is used as the independent variables in statistical analysis. Hence, the formula to be used would be something like this:

```
DV ~ T1_QOL_social + T2_QOL_social + T3_QOL_social + T4_QOL_social + T5_QOL_social
```

where T represents the time point, QOL represents the name of the questionnaire, and the suffix represents any given facet.

What I have done so far is:

```
facet_names <- c("social", "psychological", "physical", "emotional")
container <- list()

for (i in facet_names) {
  for(j in 1:5) {
    container[[i]][[j]] <- paste0("T", j, "_QOL_", i)
  }
}
```

The above creates a list with elements (facets) containing sub-elements (time point * facet) that could be used as inputs to build a formula. It looks something like this (results abbreviated):

```
$social
$social[[1]]
[1] "T1_QOL_social"

$social[[2]]
[1] "T2_QOL_social"

$social[[3]]
[1] "T3_QOL_social"
```

I need to collapse the list such that there are only 4 elements (facets) in the list, with each element containing the independent variables portion of the formula. At the same time, I need to add in operators ("+") in between the sub-elements in order for it to appear as a formula.

I've searched Stackoverflow and couldn't find a solution that involves not only collapsing a list, but pasting strings (e.g. "+") in between them. The closest I got is this question here, which merges sub-elements across elements rather than all sub-elements across a given element:

[Collapsing lists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617099/collapsing-lists-in-r)

My ideal output is as follows:

```
$social[[1]]
[1] "T1_QOL_social + T2_QOL_social + T3_QOL_social + T4_QOL_social + T5_QOL_social"

$psychological[[1]]
[1] "T1_QOL_psychological + T2_QOL_psychological + T3_QOL_psychological + T4_QOL_psychological + T5_QOL_psychological"

$physical[[1]]
[1] "T1_QOL_physical + T2_QOL_physical + T3_QOL_physical + T4_QOL_physical + T5_QOL_physical"

$emotional[[1]]
[1] "T1_QOL_emotional + T2_QOL_emotional + T3_QOL_emotional + T4_QOL_emotional + T5_QOL_emotional"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm very skeptical that you approaching the modeling correctly. I suspect your model should have three independent variables: time, QOL and the "x" value at a time and QOL. It maybe also should be a mixed effects / panel model.

Comment: @Roland I get you. My employers wanted me to replicate what some researchers did, so I'm trying things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `lapply` -

```
facet_names <- c("social", "psychological", "physical", "emotional")

lapply(facet_names, function(x) 
        paste0(sprintf("T%d_QOL_%s", 1:5, x), collapse = ' + '))

#[[1]]
#[1] "T1_QOL_social + T2_QOL_social + T3_QOL_social + T4_QOL_social + T5_QOL_social"

#[[2]]
#[1] "T1_QOL_psychological + T2_QOL_psychological + T3_QOL_psychological + T4_QOL_psychological + T5_QOL_psychological"

#[[3]]
#[1] "T1_QOL_physical + T2_QOL_physical + T3_QOL_physical + T4_QOL_physical + T5_QOL_physical"

#[[4]]
#[1] "T1_QOL_emotional + T2_QOL_emotional + T3_QOL_emotional + T4_QOL_emotional + T5_QOL_emotional"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` with `stringr`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
facet_names <- c("social", "psychological", "physical", "emotional")
map(facet_names, ~  str_c('T', 1:5, '_QOL_', .x, collapse=" + "))
```